# How does visual studio know to build parameters to web service as byte array?

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have a wsdl for a WCF web service. When I add a reference to the http://url.svc for the service visual studio builds the reference and I can reference it in code. One of the webservices exposes byte[] as one of the parameters. And when I build the client it knows this. However when I look through the .wsdl for the service I cannot see any references to to the byte array. Im really wondering how .net knows to use this as the parameter..? I wasnt aware a byte array was something you could send over the wire as a standard?

Comment: Can you show the part of the wsdl that you're referring to?

Comment: The default mapping for a byte[] is xsd:base64Binary. Are you seeing that in the wsdl ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the DataContractSerializer, all the details for how different .NET types map to WSDL / XSD are in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx (see "Type / Primitive Mapping" section). In particular, the commenter above was right, byte[] maps to base64Binary.